# org-indent-mode prevents first-line paragraph indents

Tags: org-mode, indentation, paragraphs

I'm a writer (non-programmer) using `org-mode` mainly for prose notes/planning and writing.

I'm trying to enable first-line paragraph indents for text under Org headings. I discovered `paragraph-indent-mode`, and after enabling it to no effect, I finally realized that it doesn't work, and Org's normal ability to first-line indent also doesn't work, when `org-indent-mode` is enabled. With the latter enabled, `M-i` indents the whole paragraph.

Are the two features incompatible? Ideally I would have my text body indented under the headline as per normal `org-indent-mode`, and then `M-i` would allow me to further indent the first line of a paragraph from the new margin (if I wanted to).

E.g.,

```
  * org heading
    a paragraph nicely indented and aligned to the heading text (thx org-indent, you're really great, i'd hate to have to lose you just to enable first-line paragraph indents!). sentence sentence blah blah waffle waffle
        a new first-line indented prose paragraph starting here.

    and back to non-indented new paragraph still possible if i wanted to.
```

The idea is just to have the two types of paragraph breaks available.

I also have `variable-pitch-mode` and `org-bullets-mode` enabled.

edit:
* M-i is bound to tab-to-tab-stop.

- i'm running emacs 26.1 and org latest from melpa (9.3)
- if i first run org-fill-paragraph, then the indentation works, but i don't at all like the idea of using that for my writing.
- (i also have indent-tools installed (but disabled by default in org buffers). if i run indent-tools-indent, i also get whole paragraph indenting.)

Comment: Paragraphs usually require an empty line between them. Try doing `M-x forward-paragraph` at various places in your buffer and see what you get. In particular, `a new first-line indented paragraph` is no such thing: it is still part of the first paragraph.

Comment: Other than that, I find that `M-i`, which is bound to `tab-to-tab-stop` in my case, indents the first line of a paragraph as you want and the indentation survives a `M-q` (`org-fill-paragraph`).

Comment: thanks for the tip. i wouldn’t mind it not “really” being a paragraph if i could actually still insert it. with  org-indent-mode enabled, i cannot do anything but indent an entire paragraph, which is a feature i never actually need. it’s more the visual flexibility that i’m after.

Comment: Is `M-i` bound to `tab-to-tab-stop` in your case as it is in my case? I cannot reproduce the problem you are seeing. You might also add the org version (and possibly the emacs version) to your question: it might depend on the version.

Comment: it is indeed. with org-ident-mode enabled that command indents a whole paragraph (or actually, seeing as you definied an emacs paragraph for me: technically it indents all text until a newline). only with org-indent-mode disable does it indent only the first line of text.  i take it by your comment that what i'm trying to achieve is possible and even normal... maybe i have some other half-baked config messing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible with `org-indent-mode` turned on. Maybe you can trick the mode by inserting some invisible character before inserting the space/tab:

```
(defun org-indent-paragraph ()
  (interactive)
  (forward-line 0)
  (if (looking-at "^¶")
      (while (looking-at "^¶\\|[ \t]")
        (delete-char 1))
    (insert (propertize "¶" 'font-lock-face 'org-hide))
    (insert "\t")))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-plain-text-functions
             (lambda (text _backend _info)
               (replace-regexp-in-string "¶" "" text)))
```

Comment: hm nice. this is fine for my needs. the only thing is that my init errors on org-export-filter-plain-list-functions. i gather that part of the function is to remove the invisible characters on export?

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: "Symbol's value as variable is void: org-export-filter-plain-text-functions"

Comment: You may have to require ox.el: `(require 'ox)`.

Comment: still same issue with that. i'm unsure what's wrong there. i use org-export to various formats.... :/

Comment: You have to add the code *after* requiring ox.el. IOW you need to tell Emacs where that variable is defined before you can actually use it.